# Symfony routing stopped working when not in requirements list

Tags: php, symfony, routes, default, requirements

When I first set the project up (in 3.1.4), I set up for the default route a list of default values for the variable to be sent in (locationId) and another route to catch anything that was not in the list and route it to a default value. This stopped working when I tested it again recently, so I set up a new default symfony project and just modified the DefaultController to (this is in 3.1.5):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{locationId}", name="homepage", requirements={"locationId": "L|CH|GCB"})
     */
    public function indexAction($locationId = "L")
    {
        echo $locationId;

        return new response('<br>blah');
    }

    /*
     * NOTE: This route is just used for any values that are not matched so they go to L
     * @Route("/{locationId}")
     */
    public function nocampAction($locationId)
    {
        return $this->indexAction();
    }
}
```

This SHOULD mean that if /path/to/app_dev.php/L is called, it would then echo L and blah. If L is replaced with CH or GCB it should echo them. However, if a value is sent through that is none of these it should default to L. But when I try /path/toapp_dev.php/LLL I get the route can't be found message!

Any idea why this is happening? It never triggers the second route.

NOTE: This test DOES work (old project I cut the code out of so 3.1.4):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/{varname}", name="homepage", requirements={"varname": "1|2|3"})
     */
    public function indexAction($varname = "Cool")
    {
        echo $varname;
        return new Response("<br>default");
    }

    /**
     * NOTE: blah
     * @Route("/{varname}")
     */
    public function novarAction()
    {
        return $this->indexAction();
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/test/{varname}")
     */
    public function testAction()
    {
        echo "testAction";
        return new Response("OK");
    }
}
```